# How can i append rails form_helper tag to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have to append the rails select_tag code after the click event,

this is the code,

```
var result = '<%=select_tag("repeat_time", options_for_select(get_repeat_time_list_daily, "1")) %>';
$("#repeat_time_area").html(result);
```

and it has this error,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and this is the html parsed code,

```
var result = '<select id="repeat_time" name="repeat_time"><option value="1" selected="selected">1일</option>
<option value="2">2일</option>
<option value="3">3일</option>
<option value="4">4일</option>
</select>'
```

as you can see, rails code automatically makes a new line and that cause the problem.

```
var result = '<select id="repeat_time" name="repeat_time"><option value="1" selected="selected">1일</option><option value="2">2일</option><option value="3">3일</option> <option value="4">4일</option></select>'
```

this is my expected way.

I tried all kind of things to make this as a `straight string line without new line`

```
.gsub, h, html_safe, gstrip
```

but all this kind of libs are not working :(

any good solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) or alias `j()` helper to escape carriage returns, single and double quotes for JS arguments as:

```
var result = '<%= j select_tag("repeat_time", options_for_select(get_repeat_time_list_daily, "1")) %>';
$("#repeat_time_area").html(result);
```